# How is the member access (dot) operator on structures in C interpreted?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

We have the dot operator in structures to access a particular element of struct.

Now if I have a structure:

```
struct x { 
    int a; 
    float b;
};
```

and I create an object `struct x obj`, then how exactly `obj.b` is interpreted in the compiler in order to access b? **How is the address location of b in the structure computed?**

Comment: Just curious: how did you come up with the word `StackOverFlow` in camel-case structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every instance of `struct x` will have the same layout, which is determined according to the ABI of your platform.  The C standard puts some requirements on this layout, such as that members must be arranged in declaration order, but platforms have considerable flexibility concerning alignment and padding.

The layout of data type `struct x` will be combined with knowledge of where `obj` begins in memory, in order to locate `obj.b`.  If you are interested in learning the layout, you might want to use the `offsetof` macro found in `<stddef.h>`.